# Cannot restart wamp after enabling module

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, wampserver

http://www.reloadedpc.com/other/setup-wamp-svn-subversion-windows/

I am following this guide. But I am using latest files.

> Latest WAMP with
> Apache 2.4.9
> PHP 5.5.12
>
> Latest SVN 1.8.13 from https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows using last option: Win32Svn (32-bit client, server and bindings, MSI and ZIPs; maintained by David Darj)
>
> Latest TortoiseSVN-1.8.11.26392-x64-svn-1.8.13.msi

I also installed modules for 2.4.x when prompted during setup of SVN.

I copied mod_authz_svn.so and mod_dav_svn.so tp wamp/bin/apche/apache2.4.9/modules

But couldn't find libdb44.dll(as mentioned on page) so I copied it from older version of svn and also copied intl3_svn.dll and libdb48.dll from latest svn to wamp/bin/apche/apache2.4.9/bin
I added following lines in httpd.conf of Apache

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so -> (By default present in wamp and works)
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so -> (By default present in wamp and works)<br><br>
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so -> (Copied as mentioned above and **) <br><br>
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so -> (Copied as mentioned above and **)
```

** -> These lines or files prevent my wamp from turning green after restarting all services. To be precise they give some error and prevent apache from starting.

(I found that many people are facing this problem and no result of this so far... People are moving on to some other SCCS/VCS)

Update:-

here is my error log

```
[Sun May 03 16:58:11.694326 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4856:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 03 16:58:11.695326 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4856:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sun May 03 16:58:11.695326 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4856:tid 388] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sun May 03 16:58:11.696326 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4856:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6004
[Sun May 03 16:58:12.235357 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6004:tid 304] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun May 03 16:58:23.019974 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4856:tid 388] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun May 03 16:58:25.021089 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6004:tid 304] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun May 03 16:58:25.049090 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4856:tid 388] AH00430: Parent: Child process 6004 exited successfully.
[Sun May 03 16:58:31.353451 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5508:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 03 16:58:31.353451 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5508:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sun May 03 16:58:31.353451 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5508:tid 388] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sun May 03 16:58:31.354451 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5508:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5088
[Sun May 03 16:58:31.798476 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5088:tid 304] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun May 03 16:59:05.174385 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5508:tid 388] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun May 03 16:59:07.174500 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5088:tid 304] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun May 03 16:59:07.189500 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5508:tid 388] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5088 exited successfully.
```

Comment: It would be useful to see what errors you are getting in the error log. Add them to your question using `edit`, dont put them in a comment

Comment: I also assume you did not follow this instruction `Bind to Apache 2.2.x` as you are using `Apache 2.4.x`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Posted my error log file. No, I never got that Bind to Apache stuff option anywhere while installing any of the three thing. But in latest installation of SVN I do got an option that asked my Apache version for Module (as I mentioned) and I did select 2.4.x

Comment: Did you install WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: 64 bit as my system is 64-bit! xP and I am just now installing everything on my another laptop which is 32-bit to test if thats the problem!

Comment: I am using Windows 7 amd 32-bit makes no change. Its still the there, the error. Oh I am sorry xP is just an expression like :P. My bad Really sorry

Comment: Ah the binaries you downloaded for SVN say they are compiled with VC6. They wont run with Apache 2.4.9 as that is compiled with VC11. Binaries are not compatible.

Comment: Oh man... now what do you suggest. I want to setup a Version control system for my server with WAMP @RiggsFolly BTW after I passed this error I am facing another error in working

Comment: Better ask another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally it seems to me I got this working!

> Install 32-bit WAMP
>
> Install SVN from above link
>
> Copy intl3_svn.dll and libdb48.dll from svn/bin to wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.x/bin
>
> Copy mod_authz_svn.so and mod_dav_svn.so to wamp/bin/apche/apache2.4.9/modules

You may want to move all .so and .dll files to `/modules/svn` (create this folder) in apache, just pre-cautionary!

Add those 4 lines from above question

If you moved files from bin to `modules/svn` just edit `modules/mod_authz_svn.so` to `modules/svn/mod_authz_svn.so` and so on

restart wamp and it works!

Now lets see if I can set up SCCS for my server!

Comment: Hi, I tried setting up an apache subversion server following your steps. After I made the edits to httpd.conf file, I am not able to start the apache server to run. Did you face any such problems?